# how do i create help files in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, html-help-workshop

can I create help files in html help and add it to vb.net or are there another way to implement help system on vb.net I want to create custom help files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .CHM file format (Compiled HTML) is the current format used for help files wit Winforms/WPF .Net application.

There are a variety of ways to create CHM files. I'd suggest checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023/what-are-good-tools-for-creating-compiled-html-help-files-chm) for more details on how to accomplish this.

For ASP.Net applications, you would need to generate your own help pages.

**Tutorials**

[Creating help files and linking them to a VB application](http://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=399)

**[MSDN Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3ztx0at.aspx)**

Comment: The first tutorial link is broken. Here's the link on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20150618075808/http://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=399